# $stateChangeError is not redirecting to home page

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am trying to redirect page to the home if user don't have access but looks like the $location.path('/') and  $state.go('main') both are not working. need help to solve this issue. Any idea ?

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/main/main',
            controller: 'fegMainCtrl'
    })
        .state('user-admin', {
            url: '/admin/users',
            templateUrl: 'partials/admin/user-list',
            controller: 'fegUserListCtrl',
            resolve: {
                auth: function(fegIdentity, $q) {
                    if(fegIdentity.currentUser && fegIdentity.currentUser.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1) {
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        return $q.reject('not authorized');
                    }
                }
            }
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
        if(rejection === 'not authorized'){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                $location.path('/');
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I am facing almost the same issue. Have you found the problem or any other solution? *Obs: the fourth parameter for the stateChangeError is "fromState" and the sixth is the given error. See [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)*

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to replace **$location.path( '/state/url' )** with **$state.go( 'state.name' )**.

In your case (attention to the $stateChangeError parameters):

```
$rootScope.$on( "$stateChangeError", function( event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, rejection){
    if( rejection === 'not authorized' ){
        return $state.go( 'main' );
    }
});
```

Comment: The real issue was parameter for $stateChangeError (event, current, previous, rejection) was wrong it only works for ngRoute for UI Router we need (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, rejection) and it works fine for me with $location.path( '/state/url' ).